# How to grep a line who has execution time greater than X

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have this line in my log

> invokeSuperLambda execution time:xxs

Where xx is the time of execution and s is a static letter

When I run this on my log file

```
grep -a "invokeSuperLambda execution time" /root/.pm2/logs/proxy-out-1.log
```

I get this

```
2019-01-13 07:36:44.783,123@127.0.0.1:57888: << @@@@ Lambda     
:invokeSuperLambda execution time:0s
2019-01-13 07:37:02.909,456@127.0.0.1:58952: << @@@@ Lambda 
:invokeSuperLambda execution time:14s
2019-01-13 07:38:09.820,234@127.0.0.1:54992: << @@@@ Lambda 
:invokeSuperLambda execution time:1s
2019-01-13 07:38:11.866,777@127.0.0.1:59132: << @@@@ Lambda 
:invokeSuperLambda execution time:357s
```

I need a way to filter only lines with an execution time greater than 10s so in the above example I need to get this 2 lines:

```
2019-01-13 07:37:02.909,456@127.0.0.1:58952: << @@@@ Lambda 
:invokeSuperLambda execution time:14s
2019-01-13 07:38:11.866,777@127.0.0.1:59132: << @@@@ Lambda 
:invokeSuperLambda execution time:357s
```

Comment: Why are you getting the "`@@@@ Lambda`" lines back from `grep`? Did you insert linebreaks in the question?

Comment: can't test right now : `grep -a "...time:[0-9]{2,}s" file`, you may need a grep -E.

Comment: @Archemar `{2,}` requires `-E`, yes.

Comment: This works perfect for me grep -a -E "invokeSuperLambda execution time:[0-9]{2,}s" /root/.pm2/logs/proxy-out-1.log Thank you @Kusalananda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per comment

```
grep -a -E "invokeSuperLambda execution time:[0-9]{2,}s" /root/.pm2/logs/proxy-out-1.log
```

where

- `-E` means Extended regular expression
- `[0-9]{2,}` 2 or more of char `0` to char `9`

Comment: Without trying to be overly fussy: this solution does not actually answer the original question. The proposed solution will return all lines with 2+ digit execution times, including 10 seconds, while the question asked for "only lines with an execution time *greater than* 10s".

Comment: @ozzy ... `:(1[1-9]|1[0-9]{2,}|[2-9][0-9]+)s` would do it then.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with script like this:

```
TIMEX=10
awk -F\: -v timex=$TIMEX '{if (int($NF) > timex) print}' /root/.pm2/logs/proxy-out-1.log
```

Adding your grep script become something like:

```
TIMEX=10
grep -a "invokeSuperLambda execution time" /root/.pm2/logs/proxy-out-1.log|awk -F\: -v timex=$TIMEX '{if (int($NF) > timex) print}'
```

Comment: This solution does not appear to work; it returns the line with an execution time of 1s, for instance. I also don't really understand what the thought behind it is.

Comment: @ozzy, edited, now should work fine.

Comment: Ah, now I see. Nice. Btw, there is still a typo in the second line (`inf` instead of `int`).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the lines continue after "Lambda", as suggested by the OP, this command should work:

```
gawk 'match($0, /execution\stime:([0-9]+)s/, a) && a[1] > 10 { print $0 }' logfile
```

with 'logfile' being the name of the logfile (/root/.pm2/logs/proxy-out-1.log)

This solution uses the `match` function to capture the execution time as a parenthesized group, and then bases a numerical comparison on the captured value to decide if the line should be printed.

The longer but more portable version is:

```
awk 'match($0, /execution time:([0-9]+)s/) && substr($0, RSTART+15, RLENGTH-16 ) > 10 { print }' testfile
```

Comment: You can use only `print` instead of `print $0` in most `awk` implementation it do the same

Comment: The `match` function with 3 arguments is a GNU-specific extension: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-match_0028_0029-function

Comment: @glennjackman I thought my system's 'awk' was actually 'mawk', but it isn't; it's genuine 'gawk' :-) For completeness' sake, I looked up how to do it portably, and added it to the answer. Thanks for noticing.